# How disable window move inside an area?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to write a circuit designer software in QT on Linux. I'm using KDE 5 Plasma desktop and QTCreator as an IDE.

I tried to use QFrame paintEvent to paint on it, and it worked, but when im grabbed the window inside QFrame it moved.

I know about QGraphicsView, but i cant make a custom class and promote it based on that(it's not listed).

How can i create a custom class from a container(QFrame, QGraphicsView or anything) where i can override paint event and also it doesn't move window if i grab it?

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Can you show exactly how you do things? You put a  `QWidget` (or `window`) as child of your main `QFrame`? Or is it when your `QFrame` is grabbed? I don't understand how they can be grabbed in the first place except for the top-level window, so a very basic example with some code would help

Comment: I create a QT Designer Form Class and select QFrame and lets say i name it canvas. After i put down a QFrame in MainWindow.ui and and promote it to ,,canvas". Now i have a class where i can override paintEvent, but if i left click inside QFrame(on runtime) and move my mouse, the whole window is moving. QGraphicsView is not moving, but it's not listed where i create ,,QT Designer Form Class".

Comment: I created a new qt project, put a `QFrame` with a green background in the middle of the main window http://i.imgur.com/h5uzjL2.png and clicking it and moving doesn't do anything, it stays in place and the window doesn't move either. Can you provide a short, minimal example where the problem still happens?

Comment: I did the same and mine is moving. Maybe it's my OS's setting. Is there a way then, to create a "QT Designer Form Class" from QGraphicsView? Or override QGraphicsView's paintEvent in an other way? QGraphicsView doesn't move my window.

Comment: `QGraphicsView` inherits from `QAbstractScrollArea` which inherits from  `QFrame`. So you can just put a `QFrame`, make your canvas class inherit from `QGraphicsView` and promote the `QFrame` to your canvas class. (Although, in the long term, you should have a look at qml and see if it's better to use)

Comment: Although I just tried and I can put a GraphicsView on the .ui, and then right click it to promote it in whatever class I want.

Comment: I created QFrame class, rewrite it to be inheirted from QGraphicsView, did put down a QGraphicsView on UI designer and promoted it to my custom class :) Thank you so much. Wasted half a day for it :( I dont want to learn qml, i just want to write this software for myself, did it on .net but now i switched to Linux and want to port it(i do know about GTK, but want to use it with QT). What should i do with the question? If you write an answer how to promote a QGraphicsView i accept it.

Comment: Isn't there 2 options? 1 is where i can make my class "promotable" and one where i can promote an object to one of my "promotable" classes. Whatever, working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QGraphicsView` inherits from `QAbstractScrollArea` which inherits from `QFrame` itself.

So you can keep the `QFrame` in the form, and keep it promoted to your canvas class, but simply make you canvas class inherit `QGraphicsView` instead.

Although, my Qt has two differences in behavior from the OP (but I don't use KDE):

- Clicking on a `QFrame` and moving the mouse doesn't move the whole window for me. I guess this behavior for the OP could be changed by reimplementing `void mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )` in the canvas class and giving it an empty code instead. ([doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent))
- I can put `QGraphicsView` in my ui files, and I can right click on them to promote them to another custom-defined class.

Edit: Found the [reason](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=91430) why the window moves on KDE!